# draw shadows with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello someone can you help me? I need to draw the pic show below, thanks+ you for your help.

[image]

Comment: You should show your try first, and provide a MWE. Also know how to accept an answer by ticking the checkmark. A start for you `\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[<-,blue] 
(-4,0) node[below]{$-\infty$}--
(0,0) node[below]{$-\dfrac{b}{a}$}
node[midway,above]{$x$}
;
\draw[->] (0,0)--(1.5,0) 
node[below]{$+\infty$} 
node[above]{$\mathbb{R}$}
;
\fill[blue] (0,0) circle(1.5pt);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: You asked 10 questions, non of them has an accepted answer. Most most of them show just an image and not a single line of code, i.e. "just do this graphic for me" questions. These are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.